# Error NG1010: Value at position 12 in the NgModule.declarations of HomeModule is not a reference Value could not be determined statically

Tags: angular, nodes

In my Angular 15 app, I have a submodule that's imported into AppMoodule using lazy-loading as follows:

```
{ path: PathVariables.HOME, loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then(m => m.HomeModule),canActivate
```

The app running well from my dev env but when deploying on the Heroku server, the nested module an all its child components are not found.

```
Error: src/app/home/home.module.ts:18:48 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './authentification/gestion-des-permissions/gestion-des-permissions.component' or its corresponding type declarations.
18 import { GestionDesPermissionsComponent } from './authentification/gestion-des-permissions/gestion-des-permissions.component';
                                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error: src/app/home/home.module.ts:19:37 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './authentification/roles/liste-roles/liste-roles.component' or its corresponding type declarations.
19 import { ListeRolesComponent } from './authentification/roles/liste-roles/liste-roles.component';
                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error: src/app/home/home.module.ts:22:39 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './authentification/roles/modification/modification.component' or its corresponding type declarations.
22 import { ModificationComponent } from './authentification/roles/modification/modification.component';
                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error: src/app/home/home.module.ts:31:17 - error NG1010: Value at position 12 in the NgModule.declarations of HomeModule is not a reference
  Value could not be determined statically.
 31   declarations: [
                    ~
 32        AdresseComponent,
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
... 
 50        ListeRolesComponent
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 51   ],
    ~~~
  src/app/home/home.module.ts:44:8
    44        ActivitesComponent,
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Unknown reference.
-----> Build failed
```

We are on it but we are all new Angular devs.

Comment: sounds like you are not building the app. this link might help https://medium.com/geekculture/how-to-easily-deploy-your-first-angular-app-on-heroku-65dd546c8181

Comment: Thanks so much.
My issue was a cicular dependancies in the application. causing some faillures that made thoses components import impossible. i don't know why but  locally my build didn't execute the tests.
Everything is running good now.